# "Python for Data Analysis" tutorial code runs unpredictably - US Baby Names proportions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working through Wes McKinney's *Python for Data Analysis*. While I'm working in Python 3 and the book is written in Python 2, this is generally not an issue, and if anything a good exercise.

However, I've reached an impasse on Chapter 2, example 3: US Baby Names 1880 - 2010 (pg. 34). The purpose of the following code is to insert a column titled 'prop' that contains the fraction of babies given a name for each year and gender into the dataframe:

```
def add_prop(group):
    births = group.births.astype(float)
    group['prop']=births/births.sum()
    return group

names=names.groupby(['year','sex']).apply(add_prop)
```

'names' is a dataframe with five columns ('name', 'sex', 'births', 'year', and this adds 'prop') and approximately 1.7 million rows. In order to test whether prop was added correctly, you then test when the proportions sum to approximately 1 with `np.allclose(names.groupby(['year','sex']).prop.sum(), 1)`.

My problem is that the function runs unpredictably. Perhaps once out of every 15 or 20 runs np.allclose will be true, and the function will have been applied to the dataframe correctly. Otherwise np.allclose is false. Additionally, it's wrong in different ways. Later you use this dataframe to graph the proportion of births represented in the top 1000 names by sex, and the shape of that graph changes constantly. [Some examples of graph change: [image: Some examples of graph change]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR2a2.png) I know the problem is in how proportion is being calculated and added because the rest of the dataframe doesn't vary.

What is introducing unpredictability into this example? While I suspect it's the .apply() command, I'm not sure and don't know how to test my hypothesis. It's been suggested to me that part of the code block is deprecated, but Jupyter Notebook doesn't come up with a warning and I haven't been able to find anything online. I've gone over my code twice, and overall it's virtually identical to the book's, and is identical in the case of this block. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW this code works for me as expected (pandas 0.17.1), after building what I think is the right `names`.  If we were on github I'd ask for the output of `pd.show_versions()` --  I know there's been some flakiness involved with certain numexpr setups in the past.  Out of curiosity, does `df["prop"] = df.births / df.groupby(["year", "sex"])["births"].transform(sum)` give a consistent result?

Comment: @DSM Yes, `df["prop"] = df.births / df.groupby(["year", "sex"])["births"].transform(sum)` always works correctly. And I'm using pandas 0.17.1 as well.

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce this problem without buying the book?

Comment: @Goyo The book is widely available online as a pdf.

Comment: @Cadmium yep, and everything looks ok here, with python 3.4 and pandas 1.7.1.

Comment: Well, I appreciate you both looking at it. The problem still remains on my version, but I suppose I'll just have to leave it be for now since it's not impeding anything.

Comment: @Cadmium: which version of `numexpr` are you using?  Someone else just asked a question about instability which was also a numexpr problem, so I want to rule that out..

Comment: @DSM numexpr 2.4.4 (and numpy 1.10.1, if that's relevant). I wasn't importing numexpr specifically in this case, although I have it installed via anaconda.

Comment: @Cadmium: 2.4.4 is known to be flaky, and I've opened a ticket to formally blacklist it (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12489)).  Could you try upgrading it and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @DSM I updated numexpr to 2.5, and the code works perfectly every time. Can confirm that it was numexpr 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in using a float data type for prop.  Floats are bad where you need accuracy. That's why, in the book, he says the sum of the props should add to 1 or are "sufficiently close to (but perhaps not exactly equal to) 1"

I'm new to python myself so I don't know the best solution.  In databases I avoid floats and use the decimal data type.  Regardless, if we're going to find the proportion of each of over a million records, it's going to be tough to maintain any single accuracy.